# Получить главный ключ по трем уровням

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Задача следующая:
Есть табличка `keys` со столбиками:
`key | bind`
Где `key` - это ключ, а `bind` - это так сказать привязанный`key`.
Пример:

```
key1
key2  key1  
key3  key1  
key4  key1  
key5  key2  
key6  key5
```

Суть в том, что привязка работает следующим образом:
Берем определенный ключ:

- **key1**

  - key2

    - key5

      - key6
  - key3
  - key4

Выводится все правильно.
Вопрос:
Как написать функцию, которая будет брать главный ключ - со второго и 3 уровня?
Пример:
Берем `key6` вывести должно `key1`, берем `key5`, вывести должно `key1`, берем `key2` вывести должно `key1`.
Более 3 уровней быть не должно, а также не должно уходить выше - имеется ввиду, что если у `key1` появится `key0`, то с `key6` не должно прыгнуть выше `key1`, `key5`, должен возвращать `key1`, `key2` должно вернуть `key1` - последовательность должна сохраниться `key0` не должен выводиться.

Не могу написать сам алгоритм, не въеду никак, пожалуйста помогите.

Comment: Что вам мешает максимум три раза применить условие для проверки наличия родителя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select coalesce(T2.bind, T1.bind, T.bind, T.`key`)
  from Table1 T
  left join Table1 T1 on T1.`key`=T.bind
  left join Table1 T2 on T2.`key`=T1.bind
 where T.`key`='key6'
```

Тест на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30fe58e/1)

Если ни одного вышестоящего ключа не найдено, то выдает искомый ключ. Если это не требуется, а надо получить NULL, то убрать из coalesce `T.key`.

**UPD:**

```
SELECT `k2`.`bind`
AS `k2bind`, `k1`.`bind`
AS `k1bind`, `k`.`bind`
AS `kbind`, `k`.`key`
AS `kkey`
FROM `keys` AS `k`
LEFT JOIN `keys`
AS `k1`
ON `k1`.`key`=`k`.`bind`
LEFT JOIN `keys`
AS `k2`
ON `k2`.`key`=`k1`.`bind`
WHERE `key`='key6'
```